# Why is my custom POST function intermittent on IIS with SQL Server?

Tags: php

I have a function for checking if a value has been posted, and then cleaning the input.

If the value has **not** been posted, it returns false.

```
function post($key)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] !== false)
    {
        return str_ireplace("'", "''", filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    }

    return false;
}
```

It works when doing this

```
$foo = post('foo');
```

And seems to be intermittent when using it like this in an IIS SQL Server environment

```
post('foo') ?? $existingRecord->bar
```

When **not** posting foo, we should persist `$existingRecord->bar`, but sometimes we persist an empty string instead.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my `post()` function?

Comment: `??` is coalescing operator deals with `null` but not booleans

Comment: @Alex Figured that out the hard way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There **was** something fundamentally wrong with my function.

I should `return null;` instead of `return false;`

Changing it to `null` fixed everything.